# gatsby-source-strapi RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I am trying to build an image with Gatsby and Strapi Backend. Every time I initiate the process via CICD runner it uses http(s) proxy and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN
"gatsby-source-strapi" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:
failed to process
https://../../...jpg
RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xx.xx.xx:443
```

However when using e.g. curl from the runner (with proxy) it reaches the Strapi server successfully. Seems some issue with the gatsby-source-strapi plugin?

When running same process from my laptop (without using http proxy) it builds the image fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks